# Laravel Image validation not working when I try to upload ai or psd file

Tags: laravel, validation

Laravel Image validation not working. When I try to upload ai or PSD file it's showing error:

> Illuminate \ Http \ Exceptions \ PostTooLargeException No message

Also not working when trying to upload a 3Mb image file.

```
$this->validate($request, [
      'company_name' => 'required',
      'logo' => 'mimes:jpeg,jpg,png|max:1024|image',
      'address' => 'required',
      'phone' => 'required|numeric',
      'currency_code' => 'required',
      'vat_rate' => 'required|numeric'
]);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Default file upload size is 2MB

Open the `php.ini` file. Find these lines in the php.ini file and replace it following numbers: `upload_max_filesize = 64M` Save the changes and try uploading the file again. You will now get success.

You can find the path of your PHP configuration file in your **xampp/php/php.ini**(Windows User) file And don't forget to restart your server

Comment: why max:1024 not working? I mean why bypass this and check
`if ($request->file('logo')) {
    //
}`

Answer (score 1):

Try using `size` validation Rule instead of `max`, from the docs:

> size:value
>
> The field under validation must have a size matching the given value.
>   For string data, value corresponds to the number of characters. For
>   numeric data, value corresponds to a given integer value. For an
>   array, size corresponds to the count of the array. For files, size
>   corresponds to the file size in kilobytes.

```
$this->validate($request, [
      'company_name' => 'required',
      'logo' => 'mimes:jpeg,jpg,png|size:1024|image', 
      'address' => 'required',
      'phone' => 'required|numeric',
      'currency_code' => 'required',
      'vat_rate' => 'required|numeric'
]);
```

Comment: I don't want to upload AI or PSD.

Comment: In your question you have mentioned that you're trying to upload ai or psd? Am I right?

Comment: `max:1024` isn't working bcz the size is in kbs and `1024 kbs = 2MB` so you need to specify large size!

Comment: I want to upload max 2MB file but why 3 mb file uploaded and bypass validate?

Comment: Try using `size` instead of max if you want to limit the upload to 2MB. Check the updated answer @ASMSaief